# Parse an Excel Sheet in Python : From Report to Raw Data

Tags: python, excel, parsing, report, analysis

First off, forgive if this had been asked already.  I couldn't find a solution. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
I have an excel sheet that is formatted like a report. It contains blocks of data (~1500 blocks), they contain information about stuff, see attached screenshot.
[image]
I would like to:

1. Look in every cell that has the value "X" - e.g. A1
2. Copy this value "X"
3. Paste the value "X" as a header in another cell. E.g.G1
4. Copy the value of an adjacent cell e.g. B2
5. Paste the value of B2 under the header created earlier (X)
6. do the same for Y, Z,etc.

To summarize, I am trying to work with an oddly formatted report to convert it into a meaningful raw data file.

I attached an example of a block of data. 
Thank you!

Comment: Try exporting it as a csv

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it doesn't get rid of the blocks, and it doesn't group/organize the data at all.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727017/read-merged-cells-in-excel-with-python

Comment: Thanks. very similar, but I am actually interested in the third column, which is not merged, the 4th, and the 5th.

Comment: Can you update the question to clarify what you're looking for? Ideally, using a similar structure to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727017/read-merged-cells-in-excel-with-python (input data, current code, current output, desired output).