# Uneven Column Start Rows while reading in excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in an excel sheet that has some pretty poor formatting thanks to merged cells. For example, columns 1-5 start on row 5 in the excel sheet while columns 8-20 "start" on row 6 of the excel sheet because they are merged. Before I try and hackerman something together within pandas I was curious if there was a way to handle this case? Can I specify the starting row on a range of columns and have a separate starting row on a different range of columns?

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727017/read-merged-cells-in-excel-with-python

Comment: you could specify `header=None` along with `skiprows=n` to start at the data in `pd.read_excel` then pass a list to `df.columns` with your desired column names

Comment: Ah I think the best way to do it is to read in the file into 2 different dataframes. One can be the columns that start on row 5, the other can be the columns that start on row 6 then i can just join the two.