# How to read, copy or paste with merged excel cells?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to python, and I'm now using python to handle some data in excel. I met a problem when I was trying to get a merged excel cell and paste it into a new excel sheet. I tried *pd.read_excel* and pd.DataFrame.to_excel method to write the table in excel, but it gives me lots of ***NaN*** filling the spaces.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read merged cells in Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727017/read-merged-cells-in-excel-with-python)

Comment: Unfortunately `pd.DataFrame.to_excel` isn't that flexible in terms of formatting and stuff. I would look at [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) for something like this.

Comment: Thank you all, those are really helpful. I've solved this problem.