# Pandas: Some MultiIndex values appearing as NaN when reading Excel sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading an Excel spreadsheet into a Pandas DataFrame, Pandas appears to be handling merged cells in an odd fashion. For the most part, it interprets the merged cells as desired, apart from the first merged cell for each column, which is producing NaN values where it shouldn't.

```
dataframes = pd.read_excel(
    "../data/data.xlsx",
    sheet_name=[0,1,2],  # read the first three sheets as separate DataFrames
    header=[0,1],  # rows [1,2] in Excel
    index_col=[0,1,2],  # cols [A,B,C] in Excel
)
```

I load three sheets, but behaviour is identical for each so from now on I will only discuss one of them.

`> dataframes[0]`

| Header 1 | H2 | H3 | Value 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Overall | Overall |
| A1 | B1 | 0 | 10 |
| NaN | NaN | 1 | 11 |
| NaN | B2 | 0 | 12 |
| NaN | B2 | 1 | 13 |
| -------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| A2 | B1 | 0 | 11 |
| A2 | B1 | 1 | 12 |
| A2 | B2 | 0 | 13 |
| A2 | B2 | 1 | 14 |

As you can see, A1 loads with NaNs yet A2 (and all beyond it, in the real data) load fine. Both A1 and A1 are actually a single merged cell spanning 4 rows in the Excel spreadsheet itself.

What could be causing this issue? It would normally be a simple fix via a `fillna(method="ffill")` but MultiIndex does not support that. I have so far not found another workaround.

Comment: Are B1:B2 cells merged?

Comment: @ItagybaAbondanzaKuhlmann The cell showing B1 is merged with the cell showing NaN, and the two cells showing B2 are separately merged with each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read merged cells in Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727017/read-merged-cells-in-excel-with-python)

Comment: @itprorh66 I'm not familiar with the library in use there. Would rather work with Pandas if possible - it seems like it should be possible as it's working for most cells, just not the first ones?

Comment: I have the same problem but there is still no answer :(